# first max second min ordering

Tags: sql, algorithm, sorting

I have a table with float non unique numbers and I want to order them in a special way that max element will be at the 1-st place, min element at the 2-nd place, second largest element at the 3-rd place and etc. For example,

```
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
```

I would like to order as

```
1,9,2,8,3,7,4,6,5
```

**UPD:**

Combination of ordering by ascending and descending over row_number() can be a solution, e.g.

```
select c, a, d, abs(a - d)
from (select c,
             row_number() over (order by c) as a
             row_number() over (order by c desc) as d
      from t) 
order by abs(a - d)
```

But you should keep in mind that you can meet some problems due to non unique numbers, solution above will NOT work for example below

```
c | a | d
4 | 1 | 4 | 3
4 | 2 | 5 | 3
5 | 3 | 1 | 2
5 | 4 | 2 | 2
5 | 5 | 3 | 2
```

Which means that expression used under OVER statement should NOT provide many ordering possibilities

Answer (score 6):

ANSI SQL supports `row_number()`.  You can do this by using `row_number()` in a clever way:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (order by col) as seqnum_asc
             row_number() over (order by col desc) as seqnum_desc
      from table t
     ) t
order by (case when seqnum_asc <= seqnum_desc then seqnum_asc else seqnum_desc end),
         col desc;
```

The `case` is really `least(seqnum_asc, seqnum_desc)`, but not all databases support that construct.

Comment: Thank you! I think I can use order by abs(seqnum_asc - seqnum_desc) desc to remove case construct

Comment: @SergeyMalyutin . . . Your original question does not specify what to do with duplicated values.  This answer interleaves them, which seems like a very reasonable interpretation of the question.  However, if you want them grouped, then use `dense_rank()` or `rank()`.  Even your edited question doesn't specify what to do with them.